# Request Denied in Google Maps geocode API iOS

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-geocoding-api

I am trying to integrate google maps in my iOS App. I created and tried the iOS key, Server key and browser key as well. I regenerated the keys, but still gets the status as "ACCESS DENIED". I have seen many answers here, but none of the solutions work for me. I get the following response

```
This API project is not authorized to use this API. Please ensure that this API is activated in the APIs Console
```

and sometimes this

```
"error_message" : "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, with empty referer"
```

And I tried to use the regenerated key, and i get the following result.

```
"error_message" : "The provided API key is expired."
```

The solution may be simple, but I'm really stuck. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

the log or error is clear.

for use google_maps you must :

• register your app bundle in [Google Developer](https://developers.google.com/maps/?hl=en)

• get **api key** ( if you had get it before update it)
• call the google initialize in AppDelegate

```
[GMSServices provideAPIKey:GOOGLE_MAP_SERVICE];
```

Comment: I had registered the bundle in google developers and Called in AppDelegate already. Of course, I forgot to update the key in AppDelegate. But, still the error message is coming

Comment: please double check you api key & bundle in your oroject & google developer :) check only once to call  in your app

Comment: It's all the same and no mistakes anywhere.